# How to check the same condition in several Catch2 test cases

Tags: c++, testing, catch2

I have to check the some condition (eg. initial state) in several test cases. I cannot use `CHECK` in function and I would like to replace the current macro if possible.

```
#include "catch.hpp"

#define CHECK_INITIAL_STATE() \
    CHECK(first_condition); \
    CHECK(second_condition);

TEST_CASE("first_test") {
    CHECK_INITIAL_STATE();
    // do something
    // restore state
    CHECK_INITIAL_STATE();
}
```

Comment: Why can't use you `CHECK` in a function?

Comment: Thanks the answer.
Error message will refer to the line in the function not the line where the error actually happened. It's just more comfortable when I can jump to the erroneous line and I don't need to search for the place where the function was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch2 comes with this feature built-in in a very elegant way:

```
TEST_CASE("first_test") {
    CHECK(first_condition);
    CHECK(second_condition);

    SECTION("do something 1") {
        // this test is executed after the code outside of the section
    }
    SECTION("do something 2") {
        // this test is executed after the code outside of the section
        // but without executing the previous section
    }
}
```